# How to run multiple batch programs in one batch file at the same time?

Tags: python, batch-file

We are making a simple adventure game with my friends as a challenge to only use batch and python and my question is that how could we have our bot running in the same exact window while player moves around?

Comment: StackOverflow is for people to help each other with programming based issues. If you are not supplying the code you are having issues with and any highlighting problems arising from that code, your question will be deemed off topic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask refer this url and modify your question

Answer (score 0):

Threading might be a solution for you. I've not encoutered threading in Python before, but a search brought this thread up with a few examples on implementing threading, or something similar within Python.

[How to use threading in Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python)